# How to use the same generic method for validation of different types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am having an interface IValidator which has a generic method Validate and is intended to validate different objects across the application. For now I am validating User's profile and Login credentials. The problem is, when I try to validate profile or Login class, it always calls the method for the profile even when I try to validate Login details. Here's the code:

IValidator

```
 public interface IValidator
{
    List<Error> Validate<T>(T request);
}
```

UserProfileValidator

```
 public class UserProfileValidator : IValidator 
{
    public List<Error> Validate<T>(T request)
    {
       //Code for profile validation
    }
}
```

UserLoginValidator

```
 public class UserLoginValidator: IValidator 
{
    public List<Error> Validate<T>(T request)
    {
       //Code for login validation
    }
}
```

UserService

```
   private readonly IValidator _validator; 

   public UserService(IValidator validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }


 public async Task<Response> Login(UserDetail userDetail)
 {
     //this is supposed to validate login details, but validates profile instead
        var errors = _validator.Validate(userDetail); 
 }

public async Task<Response> UpdateProfile(Profile profile)
 {
        var errors = _validator.Validate(profile);
 }
```

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: It depend on how you create object of UserService.Can you please tell how you create object of user service?

Comment: Most likely you are passing `UserProfileValidator` to your `UserService` hence the behavior.

Comment: I just inject the UserService to the constructor of UserController and call the UpdateProfile or Login method

Comment: Are you using DI? How are you registering your `UserService` since its constructor requires the `IValidator`?

Comment: Yes, I am using DI with the help of autofac. Here us the code---

   builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>();

Comment: And registering all the validator classes this way:=> builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DependencyBuilder).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Validator")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you for the help, it did help me to solve this problem. I used Autofac's keyed services to Register both the validators as IValidator, then resolved by index as needed.

see this:
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this though it may not be the solution to OP's problem.

Based on what you said you are using AutoFac.

Service:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>();
```

Validators:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DependencyBuilder).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Validator")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Looking at how you register your `UserService` you are not supplying a specific `IValidator` parameter to its constructor which I think is the reason why AutoFac keeps using the `UserProfileValidator`. Logically speaking how will `UserService` know what implementation of `IValidator` to use on run-time?

I often use the following to specify parameters to my constructors.

```
builder
    .Register(r => new UserService(r.Resolve<IValidator>()))
    .As<IUserService>()
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

But the problem with this is if the DI will resolve for the `IValidator` it is still not specific.

I would suggest redesigning your code since I don't think your current design allows the `UserService` to use both `UserProfileValidator` and `UserLoginValidator`.

Probably assigning the `IValidator` per view model would be a better approach so that each view model has their own implementation of `IValidator` then you could do something like `var errors = viewModel.Validate();`.

Comment: Ok, then will I inject a single object for validation (IValidator) or separate objects in the user service? (IValidator<UserDetail> and IValidator<Profile>)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your interface to be:

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
    List<Error> Validate(T request);
}
```

Comment: For? Kindly provide an explanation for your answer.

Comment: I tried this but it fails to register with autofac and when I register both the validator classes it shows the same behavior as I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using some dependency injection registration with the default DI container or Autofac. Please provide details of how you're doing so.

Your interface is not generic, which means that your dependency injection container is registering several implementations for the same interface and when you inject it it is taking the last implementation.

Change the interface to

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
    List<Error> Validate(T request);
}
```

and inject a service `IValidator<UserDetail>` and another `IValidator<Profile>` so in essence there are different validators that use the same interface.

Using generics is ok when the implementation is generic, but in your case each validator is different therefore the DI needs to know exactly which one to use.

In autofac you should have something like

```
builder.RegisterType<UserLoginValidator>().As<IValidator<UserDetails>>();
builder.RegisterType<ProfileValidator>().As<IValidator<Profile>>();
```

Comment: Here's the code for registration of all classes containing 'Validator' keyword at the end of a class. Registering all the validator classes this way:=> builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DependencyBuilder).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Validator")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Comment: Ok, then will I inject a single object for validation (IValidator) or separate objects in the user service? (IValidator<UserDetail> and IValidator<Profile>)